# Можно ли удалить объект в Java, на который еще есть ссылки?

Tags: java

Можно ли удалить объект, из хипа,  в Java, на который еще есть ссылки?
В документации не нашел, можно ли это сделать или нет. Мне кажется что нет.

Comment: Так а почему просто не сделать объект *null* и *gc* сам удалит его

Comment: можно, но зачем? Это не Java путь.

Comment: Всё зависит ещё и от типов ссылок: https://habrahabr.ru/post/169883/

Comment: @pavel segfault'ов захотелось, видимо.

Answer (score 0):

Только если очистить все ссылки на него.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/227389)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, почему же?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, тянет пока на комментарий, надо бы дополнить примером кода, объяснением как работает строка мусора и т.д